# How to clear input buffer in c++

Tags: c++, buffer

I need to get some lines from input. These lines may contain spaces. I wrote the code:

```
string s;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    getline(cin, s); //after this i have '\n' in buffer, and it refers to TRASH AND SODOM((
}
```

This doesn't work; how can I clear the buffer?

Comment: You're mistaken, `std::getline` removes the trailing `\n` from buffer.

Comment: You mean the spaces, or the newline? As jrok said, getline removes \n that occurs at the end, but if you want to get rid of spaces, I will answer to that.

Comment: @jrok,@Erman Doser so, then the problem is not that. In full code i have cin>>n before it. And cin dont removes '\n' maybe. I can't undersatnd it completely.

Comment: Please don't remove important parts of your question when you ask it here. Otherwise, it becomes a different question that doesn't make sense.

Comment: No `cin >> s` does not remove the newline from the input stream. Actually it doesn't even get the whole line just the next space-delimited "word".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, so how can i clear input after cin>>n ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ifstream, end of line and move to next line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477408/ifstream-end-of-line-and-move-to-next-line)

Comment: possible duplicate of [clean input buffer c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991819/clean-input-buffer-c)

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX)` and `std::cin::clear()`. Much simpler i think?